# Easy Div and Linear Gradient CSS

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

Strange thing happening, when I set the height and width to 100% for the div (Snippet #1,) the div disappears yet if you were to change the div dimensions to a height of 200px (Snippet #2) and no width, the div shows up with the gradient no problem. Can someone help me understand what I'm missing here?

Snippet #1:

```
    <style>
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: black;
        }

        #grad1 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: linear-gradient(red, blue);}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="grad1">
</div>  
</body>
```

Snippet #2:

```
    <style>
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: black;
        }

        #grad1 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: linear-gradient(red, blue); }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="grad1">
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `html`'s `width` and `height` to `100%` as well.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#grad1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add position absolute in class grid1.

```css
body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }

        #grad1 {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
            position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```